# Ensure that PHP form process file is only used with specific web form page?

Tags: php, forms

I am a little new to PHP, and I have gotten in the habit of creating a specific file that handles all the form processing. 
For example, I have one PHP file that displays the actual form, let's called it "registration.php" for example, and it specifies as its action "registration-process.php". A user fills out the registration form on registration.php, hits submit, and the data is POSTed to registration-process.php because it was specified as the action file by the form.

Now my question is this: Can't someone who knows what they are doing POST data to registration-process.php without going through registration.php? This would have the potential to lead unexpected consequences.

Is there any way to ensure that registration-process.php will ONLY accept POSTed data from registration.php? Like maybe a hidden field with a value that gets encrypted via some PHP code, and that value gets checked by the registration-process.php file? I wouldn't know how to do that, however, or if that's even the best solution.

Comment: If the data is validated properly in `registration-process.php`, then why would there be any issues in receiving post data that hasn't been created from the form?

Comment: Hi Max, that is a good point! I just want to be thorough and cover all my bases. In some forms, with inputs like checkboxes and select inputs, registration-process.php would expect certain values, although it's certainly possible to validate that properly as well.

Comment: You should validate everything, because even if the request comes from your site they can still modify the HTML on your page before submitting the form. Proper & in-depth validation is a must. If you use a framework like Laravel, it most likely has form validation funtions/methods built in.

Comment: Great point, Kenyon. I did not think of this. I'll have to read up on better ways to do proper and in-depth form validation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a hidden "security token" field is a common way to verify a forms integriy. Many public forums are using this method.

Try Google for `php form security token` or check out this site:

http://css-tricks.com/serious-form-security/

Answer (score 0):

Can you only accept POST data from one location, probably. It is worth it, probably not.

As long as you are validating your form fields correctly (make sure what you're getting is within the realm of what you're expecting) there won't be any negative consequences of leaving it so anything can POST to it.

Also, technically you can send POST data to any file on the web, it just depends on what the file does with it whether or not it means anything.

Also, what Mario Werner is talking about is CSRF tokens. That won't stop other things from posting to your site, it just adds a level of security that makes sure the request came from the right place. For a detailed explanation, you can read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery